# Issues downloading jpg from ServiceM8 API

Tags: excel, vba, servicem8

I need to download all jpg's attached to a job from my ServiceM8 account. I first pull the job list json with no issues, I then pull the attachment json for the job in question with no issues but when I try to download a attachment using the .file extension it does nothing, I get a response status of "0" and no response data.

When I use the .json extension on the url I have no issues, when I use the .file extension on the url nothing happens.

Here is my current API call:

```
base_url = "https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/Attachment.file?%24filter=uuid eq {attachmentUUID}"

xmlhttp.Open "GET", url, False, M8Username, M8Password
```

The response data:

Status: `500`

Response text:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
        <p>Internal Server Error</p>
        <hr />
        <address>ServiceM8/1.0</address>
    </body>
</html>
```

Response Headers:

```
content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
content-length: 333
date: Wed, 03 Jan 2024 10:00:21 GMT
server: Apache
strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-cache: Error from cloudfront
via: 1.1 284fd7d0d63174fcd2a8845fc0a5b8ea.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-pop: MIA3-P1
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400
x-amz-cf-id: iFqKcWLLtGfDBgbAKNhzW7nR4yBQulqfpGToCNZ2VWe3BXiyJPm8gA==
```

Comment: Can you point to the relevant part of the API docs online?

Comment: It's nice to hear from you Tim, I have greatly appreciate the help you have given in the past. First I had to make a correction above, I made the mistake of putting the ".file" extension in the wrong place in the string. It should follow the word "attachment" not be at the end of the string. With this correction the response has changed to a 500. I will also add more info above with the exact response I am getting. Is there anything I can do with this?

Comment: According to https://developer.servicem8.com/discuss/5afd76b6cbdae50003fe0bb9 your GET should look like this: `https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/Attachment/2404fbd2-cff6-4222-86b4-54a6ea4dbb8b.file`

Comment: Thank you Tim, it did not answer my question but did tell me that I was climbing the wrong tree.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the issue with the response. I was trying to download the jpg, were the API was responding with a redirect to view the jpg. I still have not gotten the web browser control to size to the jpg or the opposite the jpg to size to the web browser control, any help with this would be appreciated.

If it help anyone else this is my code:

I first load all url's for the jpg's I need into a array.

```
ReDim imageUrls(1 To 1) ' Start with an array of size 1

On Error Resume Next ' Enable error handling
For i = 1 To lastRow
    If Ws1.Cells(i, "H").Value = JobUUID Then
        ' Concatenate the base URL with the file data from column A
        imageUrls(UBound(imageUrls)) = "https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/Attachment/" & Ws1.Cells(i, "A").Value & ".file"
        ReDim Preserve imageUrls(1 To UBound(imageUrls) + 1)
    End If
Next i
On Error GoTo 0 ' Disable error handling
```

Then I use a Web Browser control to view the jpg's

```
Private Sub ShowCurrentImage()
    ' Check if the imageUrls array is not empty
    If UBound(imageUrls) >= currentImageIndex Then
        ' Navigate to the current image URL with HTML code to set width and height
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim imageUrl As String
        imageUrl = imageUrls(currentImageIndex)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Len(imageUrl) > 0 Then
            ' Extract JobUUID from the imageUrl
            Dim JobUUID As String
            JobUUID = Left(Mid(imageUrl, InStrRev(imageUrl, "/") + 1), Len(Mid(imageUrl, InStrRev(imageUrl, "/") + 1)) - 5)

            ' Find JobUUID in column A of "Attachments" worksheet
            Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
            Set Ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Attachments")

            Dim jobUUIDRow As Long
            jobUUIDRow = Ws1.Columns("A").Find(JobUUID, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row

            ' Get width and height from columns F and G
            Dim imgWidth As Integer
            Dim imgHeight As Integer
            imgWidth = Ws1.Cells(jobUUIDRow, "E").Value
            imgHeight = Ws1.Cells(jobUUIDRow, "F").Value

            ' Construct HTML code with the actual dimensions
            Dim htmlCode As String
            
        If imgWidth >= imgHeight Then
                htmlCode = "<html><body style=""margin:0;""><img src=""" & imageUrl & """ style=""""></body></html>"
        Else
                htmlCode = "<html><body style=""margin:0;""><img src=""" & imageUrl & """ style=""""></body></html>"
        End If
            ' Navigate and display the HTML code
            WebBrowser1.Navigate "about:blank"
            Do While WebBrowser1.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
                DoEvents
            Loop
            WebBrowser1.Document.Write htmlCode
            WebBrowser1.Refresh
        Else
            MsgBox "Image URL is empty."
        End If
    Else
        ' Handle the case when there are no more images
        WebBrowser1.Visible = False
        btnNext.Visible = False
        btnPrevious.Visible = False
        lbClose.Visible = True
    End If
           
    GetImageSizeInPixels imgWidth, imgHeight
    
End Sub
```

With a next & prev command button to cycle through the image index.

```
Private Sub btnNext_Click()
    ' Show the next image or wrap to the first image
    currentImageIndex = currentImageIndex + 1
    If currentImageIndex > UBound(imageUrls) Then
        currentImageIndex = 1
    End If
    ShowCurrentImage

End Sub

Private Sub btnPrevious_Click()
    ' Show the previous image or wrap to the last image
    currentImageIndex = currentImageIndex - 1
    If currentImageIndex < 1 Then
        currentImageIndex = UBound(imageUrls)
    End If
    ShowCurrentImage

End Sub
```